# .Htaccess RewriteRule (Subdomain vs Request_URI)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have several domain names, each with their own multiple subdomains. 
currently, I have a global RewriteRule for any domain with a specific `Request_URI` meant for my REST APIs.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/?api/(.*)$ /api/inbound.php [NC,L]
```

Affected Url Examples:

> acct.domain1.com/api/clients/123
>
> my.domain2.com/api/tasks/2323
>
> new.domain3.com/api/products/1212

And the Rule works great!

Now I've started using these subdomains:

> api.domain1.com/api/clients/123
>
> api.domain2.com/api/tasks/2323
>
> api.domain3.com/api/products/1212

Though this still works, it's annoyingly redundant. 
So, if the Subdomain happens to be "**api**, **sandbox**, **api.test**, or any  chosen nuance I'm going to omit the **/api/** path from the URL.

How would the RewriteRule look for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examine the HTTP Host Header value with a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api(\.test)?|sandbox
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /api/inbound.php [NC,L]
```